# Itunes Connect: Availability of app to all territories not reflecting

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I released an app using the VPP program and generating redeemable codes to install. Initially, I made it available only in India, but now I changed the app availability from only India to all territories and generated new links to install the app. But when users use the links it shows an error saying **This code is only valid for customers of the India Store**. I released a new update to the app also, thinking maybe an update required to reflect. The update is live but still, the links are not working outside India.

Please help.
[image]

Error screenshot
[image]

Comment: Not related to your question. If the code in the screenshot is important (production), do blur it to avoid any misuse.

Comment: wait for 24 hours some time apple take time for release in all territories

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link : https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devcdda55918. It says that **"The App Store in the new or changed territories updates within 24 hours."** It will reflect after 24 hours.

Comment: Hi, It's been 5 days I changed, still it is not reflected.